# python list element sequence membership

Tags: python, sequence, membership

Let's say we have a reference sequence which is a list or tuple:

```
reference = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and I want to check if some sequence does exist inside the reference sequence:

```
target1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # true
target2 = ['a', 'c', 'b']  # false
target3 = ['a', 'c', 'd']  # false
target4 = ['c', 'd', 'e']  # false
target5 = ['c', 'd']       # true
```

Is there any built-in function to check this kind of sequence membership?
Thank you!

Comment: why `['a', 'c', 'b']` is `false` ? does the order matter?

Comment: Is the question whether or not a built in function exists or whether someone can provided a function which does this?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, the order matters

Comment: @Paul Rooney I wonder both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a relevant module `difflib.SequenceMatcher`.

```
def sequence_membership(target, reference):
    get_eq = lambda x: [c for c in x if c[0]=='equal']
    get_length = lambda x: x[2]-x[1]
    s = SequenceMatcher(None, target, reference)
    match_result = s.get_opcodes()
    overlapped = get_eq(match_result)
    if len(overlapped) ==1 and get_length(overlapped[0]) == len(target):
        return True
    else: return False

>>> sequence_membership(target1,reference)
True
>>> sequence_membership(target2,reference)
False
>>> sequence_membership(target3,reference)
False
>>> sequence_membership(target4,reference)
False
>>> sequence_membership(target5,reference)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first thought, you can convert the list or tuple to string and find if the substring exists in the reference. A simple code snippet to explain my thought:

```
reference = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
target1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # true

list2str = lambda ref: "".join(ref)

base = list2str(reference)
t1 = list2str(target1)

if t1 in base:
    print 'found'
else:
    print 'unfound'
```

Comment: and what if list will be `['a', 'bc', 'd']` and the target `['b', 'c']`

Comment: @Poloq, good catch. Then need to use a separator to differentiate each word in list.

Comment: @ichbinblau thank you for your answer. I want to keep the list rather than converting it to string because the spelling of the elements might cause some problem similar to what Poloq pointed out. eg. `ref = ['a','bra','cad','abra']`, `target=['abra', 'cad'] #false`